# What were the results of the 2012 European Junior Weightlifting Championships 85kg A Class?

Tags: statistics, tournaments, weightlifting, championship

I'm looking for the list of names and scores for the competitors in the 2012 European Junior Weightlifting Championships 85kg A Class

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmAEMcSGiPo

I managed to reverse image search a screenshot of the dolphin in the background to find this site:

[http://www.lifting.co.il/category/אליפות-אירופה-לנוער-2012-אילת](http://www.lifting.co.il/category/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A8-2012-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA)

However, it only goes back to 2013:

[image]

Does anyone know the actual results?

Comment: I've edited this question to be answerable on this site and re-opened it. Note that answers should include the actual results, rather than being a pointer somewhere else - any "link only" answers are highly likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

85KG MENS CLEAN & JERK:
[image]

85KG MENS SNATCH:
[image]

http://result.ewfed.com/eventlist/e/14

Comment: And a source for these?